# How to have in app notification in windows 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

Earlier in windows phone 8.1 I used to use the `ToastPrompt` provided by coding4fun toolkit. These notifications are inside the app and are very neat. Is there something like that for Windows 10 UWP. As I couldn't use the same.
Code Used currently:

```
ToastPrompt tp = new ToastPrompt() { Title = "Hi", Message = "Show the message" };
tp.Show();
```

This works on wp 8.1 winrt but fail's to run on win10 Universal.

[image]

I was looking for something like this which wouldn't show up in the action centre like a normal toast notification. But I realized that It wouldn't be nice with regards to universal apps hence implemented my own local notification. You can check out the [app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/brilli-wallpaper-changer-start-desktop-lockscreen/9nblggh5xrj6) here if you'd like to see what exactly I meant.

Comment: There was an [issue](https://github.com/Coding4FunProjects/Coding4FunToolkit/issues/6) on github about that and it seems to have been solved. Have you checked it?

Comment: @Genixius : I tried using it I've added the code which I'm trying to use. I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think that the toolkit is yet developed for windows 10 uwp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the same functionality in Windows 10. Here is a great article about the difference:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/10/a-brief-summary-of-what-is-new-different-with-toast-notification-and-action-center-in-windows-10.aspx

And here is some sample code for a UWP:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/09/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10.aspx

Comment: But this makes use of NotificationManager which shows the toast but then adds it to the action center, Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a simple notification that pops in and out and remains inside your app, I wrote a blog post on how to do it on your own (simple but effective):
http://msicc.net/?p=4365 (takes only about 30 minutes to implement).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably something like a modal dialog and not a notification. For that you can use a [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx). Copying an example from the link below:

```
using System;
private async void WifiConnectionLost()
{
    ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "No wifi connection",
        Content = "Check connection and try again",
        PrimaryButtonText = "Ok"
    };

    await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```